# can't get rid of list items height in menu

Tags: html, css, height, html-lists

hi i just wanted to code a site like BBC just for practice while doing this i got an error in `li` item of a `ul` i don't know the problem but when i give it a `border-right` the border take more height then the original menu, i'm pasting my code here please check it and help me?? 
 in simple words i want list item's border to be equal to the borders of "Signin" and "logo" div

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>BBC</title>
    <style>
    body{
    margin:0;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,freesans,sans-serif;

    }

    #top{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;

    }
    .keepcenter{
    width:1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #logo{
    border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    float:left;
    padding-right:5px;
    height:100%;
    }
    #signin{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:0.9em;
    border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    }
    #signin img{
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    margin-left:15px;
    }

    #signin p{
        display:inline;
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
        padding-left:5px;
    }
    #menutop{
    float:left; 
    }
    #menutop ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

    }
    #menutop li{
    padding:15px 20px 10px 20px;
    display:inline;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:0.9em;
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height:100%;

    }
    </style>
    </head>

   <body>
   <div id="container">
    <div id="top">

    <div class="keepcenter">

   <div id="logo">
   <img src="images/logo.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div id="signin">
   <img src="images/signicon.png" /><p>Sign In</p>
   </div>
   <div id="menutop">
   <ul>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>Home</li>
   </ul>
   </div>

   </div>
</div>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean the border takes up the same height as the li including the padding? That's normal. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/LffvtLxr/) I've included a horizontal rule below the menu, and you can see that the rule doesn't change position if you remove the border. So the border does not take up any extra vertical space. Or, did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: yes i want the border to restrict to the menu height see borders of sign in and logo they are at exact height, i just want the li border to be the same height of those two. in simple words i want list item's border to be equal to the borders of "Signin" and "logo" div

Comment: do you understand now? @Mr lister

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the top and bottom padding from the list items.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, freesans, sans-serif;
}
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.keepcenter {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#logo {
  border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}
#signin {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#signin img {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#signin p {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#menutop {
  float: left;
}
#menutop ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menutop li {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">
    <div class="keepcenter">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40" alt="BBC" />
      </div>
      <div id="signin">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/10/10" alt="" />
        <p>Sign In</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menutop">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Home</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The list is floating though, which means that its baseline is not necessarily the same as the #signin div. In my snippet, the img in the div is small enough to not have an effect, but depending on its size, the baseline of the div (and therefore the position of the p) will move down. You may have to compensate for that in the ul.

Comment: should i go with decreasing height ? as decreasing height in #menutop li can make it equal to the borders of other divs..is it a good solution? like if i reduce height to 50% then list item's borders becomes equal to other div borders.

Comment: Like I said, that depends on the sizes of the images, relative to the font size.

Comment: ok thanks sir, i have reduced its height and now it is perfect.